# In a pandas dataframe, how do you add a value to the end of each row in iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a simple dataframe with products, current prices and average prices. I want to use the current and average prices to calculate a retail price. My attempt is:

```
import csv
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os

frame = pd.read_csv('/ ... /data.csv')

for index, row in frame.iterrows():    
  product = row['product']
  price = row['price']    
  ave_price = row['ave_price']
  weight_price = 2.0
  max_price = ave_price * weight_price

  retail_price = max_price / (1.0 + 2.0 * price / ave+price)
  retail_total = rs_price * 1.0875

frame.to_csv('/Users ... /output.csv', encoding ='utf-8')
```

How do I get the retail_total and add it in such a way that I can print the entire dataframe with the products, current prices, average prices AND retail prices?

When I try to do it, it just populates ALL of the products' retail price as the last one in the list of products:

Comment: why not just add a new column `retail_price` in `frame`?

Comment: When I try to add a new column with the retail price for each product, it just adds the last retail price in the list of products across all the products. What's the correct way to add a new column retail_price in frame?

Answer (score 2):

Add a column to the frame:

```
frame['retail_price'] = Series(np.zeros(len(frame)), index=frame.index)
```

Then store the value for each row inside the for loop

```
for index, row in frame.iterrows():    
  product = row['product']
  price = row['price']    
  ave_price = row['ave_price']
  weight_price = 2.0
  max_price = ave_price * weight_price

  retail_price = max_price / (1.0 + 2.0 * price / ave_price)
  retail_total = retail_price * 1.0875

  row['retail_price'] = retail_price
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate some artificial data
# ===========================================
np.random.seed(0)
product = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), size=10)
price = np.random.randint(100, 200, size=10)
avg_price = np.random.randint(100, 200, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(product=product, price=price, avg_price=avg_price))
df

   avg_price  price product
0        125    188       E
1        177    112       A
2        172    158       D
3        109    165       D
4        120    139       D
5        180    187       B
6        169    146       D
7        179    188       C
8        147    181       E
9        164    137       A


# processing
# ===========================================
# some constant parameters
weight_price = 2.0

df['retail_price'] = df['avg_price'] * weight_price / (1.0 + 2.0 * df['price'] / df['avg_price'])

df['retail_total'] = df['retail_price'] * 1.0875

df

   avg_price  price product  retail_price  retail_total
0        125    188       E       62.3752       67.8331
1        177    112       A      156.2544      169.9266
2        172    158       D      121.2459      131.8549
3        109    165       D       54.1276       58.8637
4        120    139       D       72.3618       78.6935
5        180    187       B      116.9675      127.2022
6        169    146       D      123.9089      134.7509
7        179    188       C      115.4631      125.5661
8        147    181       E       84.9077       92.3371
9        164    137       A      122.8128      133.5589

# df.to_csv()
```